# Flutter : my custom Switch widget does not respond to state change

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-widget

I made a custom SwitchTile widget to avoid code duplication, which is based on a StatefulWidget with a boolean value so this is quiet simple :

```dart
class SwitchTile extends StatefulWidget
{
    final String title;
    final bool value;
    final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
    
    const SwitchTile({Key? key, required this.title, required this.value, required this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SwitchTileState();
}

class _SwitchTileState extends State<SwitchTile>
{
    late bool value;
    
    @override
    void initState() 
    {
        super.initState();
        this.value = widget.value;
    }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(widget.title),
            trailing: Switch.adaptive(
                value: this.value,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                    widget.onChanged(newValue);
                    this.setState(() => this.value = newValue);
                }
            )
        );
    }
    
    @override
    void dispose()
    {
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Now I want to synchronize some SwitchTile widget with another boolean value, but when the value changes it does not rebuild as I expected. I use flutter_bloc, the bloc/events/states work very well. See what I tried to do :

```dart
// See my Widget build() method ; bloc variable is declared above
BlocBuilder<ChadsVascBloc, ChadsVascState>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, ChadsVascState state)
    {
        return Column(
            children: [
                // this works very well
                ListTile(
                    title: Text("Switch : ageOver65 is ${state.ageOver65.toString()}"),
                    trailing: Switch.adaptive(
                        value: state.ageOver65,
                        onChanged: (value) => bloc.add(AgeOver65Toggled(ageOver65: value))
                    )
                ),
                // this is does not
                SwitchTile(
                    // the change is well triggered in the title property !!!
                    title: "SwitchTile : ageOver65 is ${state.ageOver65.toString()}",
                    value: state.ageOver65, // but this does not change the button's status
                    onChanged: (value) => bloc.add(AgeOver65Toggled(ageOver65: value))
                )
            ]
        );
    }
),

SwitchTile(
    title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ageOver65,
    value: bloc.state.ageOver65,
    onChanged: (value) => bloc.add(AgeOver65Toggled(ageOver65: value)),
)
```

When I push the last button, the first one work very well ("base" Switch widget) but the second one (custom SwitchTile widget) does not : the title changes but not the button's position.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : my error was not using BLoC but with bad state management structure. As a Switch widget does not have to manage its own state, my custom Switch widget should not try to changes its own state.

So it can be a simple StatelessWidget but used inside a parent StatefulWidget, or - I my case - in a BlocBuilder. I finally use a simple context.watch() as the value of my custom widget.

Comment: Would you mind to share the corrected code?

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you use the same event twice, that's why the bloc doesn't recognize any changes because you add the same event even it has the different value.

And i think you use the Bloc in the wrong way. Unlike provider and getx, main objective of Bloc is deliver the context with state. It was never meant to save some object inside it for so long.

For your case,
I assume you are trying to edit some kind of object. Use Bloc event to transfer the related object into another screen, in edit screen, Bloc will listen the state and parsing it to the local variabel that was assigned to the Switch (use BlocConsumer, listener to set state)
if u want to change the value of the variabel, go for it, and confirm it by some trigger like button then add another event to finish the edit

Comment: I don't think I made a mistake with Bloc : I trigger some events from some widgets to separate business logic from the view. And I need my view to update according to the state. My exemple was a "try" to see if me custom switch widget would be triggered... and it is not ! But that's not exactly the way I would use it, in fact I'll trigger an AgeOver65Event when another widget sends an AgeOver75Event (you can't be over 75 and younger than 65...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be : how to update properly a custom Switch widget ?
It does not seem to be about Bloc, because when I do that :

```dart
BlocBuilder<ChadsVascBloc, ChadsVascState>(
    builder: (context, state) => SwitchTile(
        title: "AgeOver65 is ${state.ageOver65.toString()}",
        value: state.ageOver65,
        onChanged: null
    ),
)
```

If I trigger a state change, ${state.ageOver65.toString()} changes but not the value of the Switch.